# How to bind image into src attribute using Angular 8

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular8

I have a requirement to bind a list of employee on UI, which is already done using ***ngFor**.

Now, I wanted to bind image for each employee using pipe. 
In pipe for every employee I have to hit the server to get the Image(it returns in Base64 format).

**Problem:** 
It's not working when I am try to get the image using ***subscriber***.

```
this.userSerivce.GetProfileImage(ntnet).subscribe(img => {
      if (img !== '' && img !== undefined && img.length > 64) {
        return prefix + img;
      } else {
        return profileImage;
      }
    });
```

And on UI in ***src attribute*** I can see this

```
src=(unknown)
```

**Note:**

If getting all images along with employee it self from API then the response become very slow due to image processing (getting img from ntnet).

**Is there any other best way to bind dynamic images on UI without freezing the UI**

Comment: can you create a small example on stackblitz.com?

Comment: But getting image from my company's ntnet server will not work.. It won't help...

Comment: @vijaysahu you can use https://placeholder.com/ to get an image

Comment: I sure it will not help but again if you guys want then I will do it... My actual issue is how to bind when you  are getting base64 image using  subscriber in pipe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try has an array of object. At first you get the users, after get all the images using forkJoin. When you has all the images, you asign the value to the property "img".

Well, when you received a imagen in base64, you need use [DomSatinize](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer), so in your constructor

```
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {}
```

Imagine you has

```
persons=[
{id:1,name:"Person 1",img:null},
{id:2,name:"Person 2",img:null}
...
]
//you create an array of observables
//and subscribe to forkJoin
forkJoin(this.persons.map(p=>this.userSerivce.GetProfileImage(p.id)))
.subscribe((res:any[])=>{
   //in res[0] you has the image of the first call
   //in res[1] you has the image of the second call
   //....
   res.forEach((img,index)=>{
     this.persons[index].img=
         this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/png;base64," + img) 
   })
 })
```

you has an .html like

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
   <img *ngIf="person.img" [src]="person.img"/>{{person.name}}
</div>
```

NOTE: I imagine you received some like:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAKT2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDI...
```

see an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8siuka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE2: In the stackblitz I replace the this.userService.GetProfileImage by a simple getImagen

Comment: Perfect answer... just one question, once the img occurred for each emp, can't we map these imgs with each emp based on their EmpId instead of using index.

Comment: I dont' understand so much. You has two arrays, one with the persons and one with the images. As we are mapped the array of persons to an array of Observables and use forkJoin, the array of images are ordered, res[0] is the response to getImagen(persons[0].id), res[1] is the response to getImagen(persons[1].id)... You can relationate the res[index] with persons[index]

Comment: Got your point, I was just little worried about the sequence/order of EmpId and their images.. means in the end it should not mismatch....

Comment: Vijay, the images can be loaded at differents times and unordered, but only when **all** the images has loaded, the forkjoin "finalize" and give us the response (of course ordered). Think that sometimes you use forJoin to get differents answers, e.g. in a dbs is tipical use forkJoin to get initials tables -and use "destructuring-, some like `forkJoin([getCategories(),getPersons(),getInvoices()]).subscribe(([categories,persons,invoices])=>{...})`